# Format <div> contents as though it were a print preview of A4/USLetter

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` whose contents represent an invoice that my server will print. Some of the stuff inside the `<div>` are `contentEditable=true`.  Each page should have various headers and footers etc.

I want the contents of this `<div>` to be presented to appear like a print preview.

Its easy to set the `width` of the `<div>` to be A4, or whatever page size.

But how to make the `<div>` height the appropriate multiple for the number of pages, and how to get the content within the `<div>` to jump across page boundaries?

Comment: Good Question. The idea is to not get the height but rather make an automatic height that adjusts based on content.

Answer (score 1):

Good Question Will:

The main idea behind that would be not to create a finite `height` adjustment but rather an automatic height - assuming that you don't have a border on your `div`

I would implement the following style:

```
[DivSelector]{
    width: [Your full A4 width - any print margins ];
    /* set minimum height to 1 page height */
    min-height: [A4 PageHeight in Px];
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto; /*  ensure that your content remains within the div */
}
```

I have tried this before but with an A3 display. Ofcourse when you print, your printer will add it's own margin so it's important to make your page with to `width: [FullPage Width - PageMarginSetOnPrinter]`

Comment: If there's a paragraph that crosses a page boundary, won't it just be rendered crossing that boundary and outside the printable page area rather than being split across two pages as it would be if printed?

Comment: Well, it will show on page two right? Which is exactly what you want. Same thing happens when you use microsoft word, when you type more info than provided, the overflow is passed to the next page. That will be the behavior when you print. or show print preview. You don't want to make a webpage that acts like a print preview, that would be unnecessary. but rather create a page with the same width as your A4 page but longer height which contains everything.